# Ошибка TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь написать программу для перевода слов, выдает ошибку. Не могу понять, как исправить.

---

Исходный код (Python 3.4):

```
#!/usr/bin/python -utt

     import requests
     import json


     url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate"
     params = {}

     params['key'] = 'trnsl.1.1.20141226T121421Z.332bfe636323b4d7.d542040fe5056cc6ab6917ff946b80c703ac6ae6'
     params['lang'] = 'en-ru'



     params['text'] = '''The weather in England changes very quickly
     and very often'''
     result = json.loads(requests.get(url, params=params).content('utf8'))

     print(result['text'][0])
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/test/test.py", line 17, in <module>
result = json.loads(requests.get(url, params=params).content('utf8'))
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Помогите исправить, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = json.loads(requests.get(url, params=params).content.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Атрибут `.content` имеет тип `bytes`. Его нельзя *вызвать*. Пример объекта, который можно вызвать — обычная функция.

Чтобы распарсить JSON-ответ, вызовите метод `.json()`, наподобие такого:

```
import requests # $ pip install requests

r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
result = r.json()
print(result['origin'])
```

Comment: @jfs: Перевёл на русский, надеюсь, вы не против.

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо. Это была ошибка с моей стороны.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое! flau, вы меня спасли!
заработало с этим

> result = json.loads(requests.get(url, params=params).content.decode(encoding='utf-8'))

Comment: Если нет особых причин, то лучше использовать: `result = requests.get(url, params=params).json()` вариант, который я предложил в моём ответе, т.к. он выглядит более читаемо.